# Error: "Thunderbolt controller has experienced an issue and cannot connect to devices or other computers until new firmware is installed"

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, thunderbolt, lenovo-vantage

I'm receiving this error on my Lenovo ThinkPad x1:

> A Thunderbolt controller has experienced a problem and cannot connect
> to devices or other computers until new firmware is installed.

Device Details:

```
Lenovo ThinkPad x1 Yoga, 2nd Generation, 20JD005WGE
```

What I tried:

- Updating Windows 10
- Updating ThinkPad BIOS and software through Lenovo Vantage - incl. Lenovo provided Thunderbolt update

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is along-running post about this problem, dating from 2018:
[Thunderbolt Controller Error](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Thunderbolt-Controller-Error/m-p/4268391).

The
[latest entry](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/Thunderbolt-Controller-Error/m-p/4268391?page=7#5190111)
from 2020-11-23 in the post says this:

> The simple solution is to DOWNGRADE Thunderbolt Software by
> uninstalling the one from Lenovo (17.4.80.550) and install the latest
> version from Intel.com: 17.4.77.400 (Attached to this message)
>
> NOW you can install the latest Thunderbolt firmware from Lenovo, but
> DO NOT re-install Thunderbolt Software 17.4.80.550 from Lenovo.
>
> Make sure to DISABLE automatic updates in Lenovo System Update &
> Lenovo Vantage to prevent this from re-occurring.
> [Intel Legacy
> Thunderbolt Software
> TBT_Legacy-Win10-64-17.4.77.400.zip](https://forums.lenovo.com/download/231430).